# mongoose populate count array field

Tags: javascript, node.js, mongoose, mongodb-query

I want to get objects with populate and field of the array that I want to count.
For Example:

```js
const ChildSchema = new mongoose.Schema({
  name: String,
  age: Number,
  siblings: [{type: ObjectId, ref: 'Child'}],
  toys: [{type: ObjectId, ref: 'Toy'}]
})
```

and I want to get a populate of the siblings and count of the toys in one object, like this:

```js
const Dan = {
  name: "Dan",
  age: 4,
  siblings: [
    {
      name: "Sally",
      age: 7
    },
    {
      name: "Ben",
      age: 10
    },
    {
      name: "Emily",
      age: 2
    }
  ],
  numOfToys: 11
}
```

I have this already:

```js
const returnedChild = await ChildModel.findById(BenId)
  .populate('siblings', 'name age')
  .select('name age siblings')
  .lean()
```

How do I include the count of the toy in the returned object?

Comment: Have you been tried this ?
https://mongoosejs.com/docs/populate.html#count

Comment: @Heartbit
There isn't field 'child' in ToySchema'.
So I can't do 
ChildSchema.virtual('numOfToys', {
  ref: 'Toy',
  localField: 'name'
  foreignField: 'child',
  count: true
});
or something like this.

Comment: And if it was an array of non ObjectId, how do you would count it?

Comment: why do you not store `child` ref inside `toys` ? every `Toy` should have a filed as `child` so you can  count all toys belongs to `child`

Answer (score 0):

Just use virtual schemas:

```
ChildSchema.virtual('toyCount').get(function () {
    return this.toys.length
});

const returnedChild = await ChildModel.findById(BenId)
  .populate('siblings', 'name age')
  .select('name age siblings')
  .lean()
console.log("Toys -> ", returnedChild.toyCount)
```